# Java: While Iterating Over Hashmap & Trying to Get an Ordered List of Chars related to Integers, I only get One of the Members of the HashMap Repeated

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> itr = myHashMap.entrySet().iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry = itr.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < newCharArray2.length; i++) {
                if (entry.getValue() < min && entry.getValue() != 0) {
                    min = entry.getValue();
                    k = entry.getKey();
                    itr.remove();
                }
                newCharArray2[i] = k;
                letterCount[i] = min;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("New newCharArray letters: " + Arrays.toString(newCharArray2));
        System.out.println("New letterCount numbers: " + Arrays.toString(letterCount));

            }
```

By using itr.remove, I am hoping to remove that key set from the map and then when it iterates again it finds the NEXT minimum of the keyset pairs of Chars to Ints.

Some information: My array of the counts of the letters (leterCount) (From A - K) is

```
[1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1]
```

And my Hashmap key pairs are:

```
myHashMap.put('A', letterCount[0]);
            myHashMap.put('B', letterCount[1]);
            myHashMap.put('C', letterCount[2]);
            myHashMap.put('D', letterCount[3]);
            myHashMap.put('E', letterCount[4]);
            myHashMap.put('F', letterCount[5]);
            myHashMap.put('G', letterCount[6]);
            myHashMap.put('H', letterCount[7]);
            myHashMap.put('I', letterCount[8]);
            myHashMap.put('J', letterCount[9]);
            myHashMap.put('K', letterCount[10]);
```

So my result of the two System.out is

```
New newCharArray letters: [A, A, A, A, A]
```

```
New letterCount numbers: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Is the remove function just not doing it's job or am I not understanding something correctly in this code? I've been working at this for hours so hopefully someone can be of help.
Oh, and the reason I'm ignoring the 0s in the code is because I'm supposedly focusing on the numbers that are 1+.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the code is supposed to do? What problem are you solving?

Comment: You seem to have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What are you _actually_ trying to do? In English, without reference to any code.

Comment: So the overall program is to sort a text file of letters. The letters are A-K and the text file is one line of each letter, always capitalized, up to 200 letters. I had a text file in this one that was: H A D B B K H D, and all those letters are on a different line. We need to display the letters in a fancy way in a display function. This above is me just working on the sorting lol. So here, I'm trying to sort the letters that have an occurence of 1 and over. I've already sorted the ones that have 0 occurences.

Comment: @Bohemian I am trying to order the letters from minimum to maximum and store them in an array (newCharArray2), as well as now get an array with the number of occurences of those specific letters ordered from least occurence to greatest occurence.

Comment: So one array would be the letters(not repeated, just the letters of least occurence to greatest occurence) and the other array would correlate the same indexes with that array of the number of times the letter is repeated.

Comment: Post those details as edits to your Question, not Comments.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using java streams as follows:

```
LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> collect = myHashMap.entrySet().stream()
   .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));

System.out.println(collect);
```

Output:

```
{C=0, E=0, F=0, G=0, I=0, J=0, A=1, K=1, B=2, D=2, H=2}
```

Comment: *The statement itr.remove() does not remove anything from myHashMap*: Not true! [Changes to the entry set are reflected in the map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet())

Answer (score 0):

The entire program is a one-liner:

```
new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt"))
  .useDelimiter("\\Z") // regex for EOF
  .next() // the whole file as a String
  .chars() // IntStream of characters
  .filter(c -> c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') // ignore newlines etc
  .mapToObj(c -> (char)c) // to Character
  .collect(groupingBy(c -> c, counting())) // char Drew's as Map<Character, Long>
  .entrySet().stream() // stream em
  .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()) // sort by value
  .map(Map.Entry::getKey) // extract key
  .forEach(System.out::println); // print em
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/IhW4Pt).

Although not specified, if you need to break frequency ties alphabetically, add `.thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())` to the sort comparator.